# Angular 5 service call not working based on modal result

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-modal

I have a delete button on the table when user click delete button basically I would like to ask confirmation from the user for delete. If use clicked yes I need to make service call. I'm facing an issue when I making service call. Below is my code and I have attached the error as well.

```
delete (id) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmationModalComponent);
    this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
        if (result === true) {
            this.userService.deleteUser(id).subscribe(response => {
                alert("Record deleted successfully");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: show code of your service `userService`

Comment: can we have a look in your deleteUser() function?

Comment: From the error it seems you are trying to set the headers wrongly for the http requests. Please share the ‘deleteUser’ function

Comment: delete user work perfectly, if i didn't ask confirmation

Comment: show code of `deleteUser`

Comment: you guys are right, problem is with delete, i have changed my code

return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + route);
to
 return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + route).map(response => {
      return response;
    });

Comment: I think you want { return response.json(); }

Comment: @ rmcsharry you are right